# Why can't I cast an object inside of an if statement?

Tags: java, casting

I haven't seen this exact question here, which surprises me.

The following will not compile:

```
public int compareTo( Object o )
{
    if ( this.order < ((Category o).order) )
    {
      return -1;
    }
    else if ( this.order > ((Category o).order) ) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Whereas changing this to cast the object and store its reference in a new object outside of the conditional statement fixes the issue:

```
Category cat = ( Category )o;
if ( this.order < cat.order )
// Etc...
```

My question is, why is this behavior not allowed in Java?  (Java 5 specifically)

EDIT: Aha! Thank you all.  Darn modern IDEs giving vague error messages.  I've begun to discount them, which didn't do me any good this time.  (Netbeans was warning me about both a missing parenthesis and a missing semicolon...)

Comment: if ( this.order < ((Category) o ).order)

Comment: There *is* a missing parenthesis.

Comment: @EJP Right, but there isn't a missing semicolon.  That was evidence both that I should have paid attention to it, but also that those messages can be wonky.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem here is that your syntax is not right. It should be

```
public int compareTo( Object o )
{
    if ( this.order < ((Category) o).order )
    {
      return -1;
    }
    else if ( this.order > ((Category) o).order ) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the syntax

```
Category.class.cast(o)
```

then you are explicit in what you are doing and it avoids any confusion with brackets. From my understanding the above is the same as ((Category) o)

Comment: Aha! Can anyone else verify this is correct?  I really like this syntax!

Comment: Well, they definitely compile down to different code. Both include a checkcast, but the `Category.class.cast(o)` method also pushes the `Category.class` to the stack and then has an `invokevirtual`. In other words, the `.class` approach has everything the cast approach has, plus some. How much of a performance impact this would have, I don't know (I would guess negligible). http://pastebin.com/7VRtfX5j

Answer (score 1):

This should be allowed, it seems as if your parenthesis may be off: have you tried something like

if ( this.order < (((Category)o).order) )

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
(((Category) o).order)
```

I just tried a simpler version of what you have:

```
int a = 5;
        if(4 < (double)a);
```

and it compiled fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is a distinct difference between the two code snippets you posted:

```
(Category o)
```

is different than:

```
( Category )o
```

This first will not compile, the second one will.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at simple **working** demo of **casting** within `if` :

```
int i;
float d = 10.5f;
if((i = (int) d) == 10){
//works
}
```

in your code problem is with `if ( this.order < ((Category o).order) )` its **incorrect** statement

it should be `if ( this.order < ((Category) o).order)`

EDIT :
Your problem solved but **one thing** more(**extra topping**), no need to have `else`(**ladder form**) as you are having `return` within `if`

```
public int compareTo( Object o )
{
    if ( this.order < ((Category) o).order )
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if ( this.order > ((Category) o).order ) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BlackVegetable one thing more there is no need to have `else` as you are having `return` within `if`