# Can I cast and work with an Object on one line?

Tags: java, syntax

Normally, I do something like this:

```
public showDialog(final Object caller) {
    JDialog dialog = [ ... ]

    if (caller instanceof Window) {
        Window w = (Window) caller;
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(w);
        w.dispose();
    }
}
```

However, is there a one-line way to do it? Basically, something like: `(Window) parent.dispose();` Or do I always need to create a Window to store my cast?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes:

```
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo((Window) caller);
```

If you want to call a method on the casted value, you'll have to enclose it into a set of parenthesis:

```
((Window) caller).dispose();
```

Personally I'd only do that if that's the *only* thing I do with it. If there are two or more statements where I needed the value with the cast, then I'd use an explicit variable as you've done in your original code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just wrap the cast in another set of parentheses:

```
((Window) parent).dispose();
```

Not particularly beautiful though.

> Or do I always need to create a Window to store my cast?

Keep in mind that you're not creating a `Window` - you're creating a reference to the `Window` you already have (which is quite cheap).

Answer (score 3):

You can write

```
if (caller instanceof Window) {
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo((Window) caller);
    ((Window) caller).dispose();
}
```

I would suggest you do what is clearer and not worry too much about the number of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. Your 3 lines would become:

```
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo((Window) caller);
((Window) caller).dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

For clarity I often cast in a slightly different way

```
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(Window.class.cast(caller));
Window.class.cast(caller).dispose();
```

This I think explicitly tells the reader what you are doing. Although the () cast syntax is commonly known I think that idiom relies on specific java knowledge.

Comment: This is fairly nice. Is it simply syntax sugar? Or is it the other way around, and the () syntax is converted to X.class.cast(y) ?

Comment: Redandwhite. in your example y is cast to x. I added this to another question a while ago and http://stackoverflow.com/a/11745449/846476 @yshavit looked at the byte code which was interesting.